# Override Plugin Function in WordPress using function from Child Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I got some trouble in here, recently I added a plugin in my WordPress, the plugin is very nice, basically it send my order to my WhatsApp, in the last line of the message has a date and, I would to change from English to PT_BR.

**On plugin code is like this:**

```
<?php

function wa_order_thank_you_override( $title, $id ) {

...

$date = date( 'F j, Y – g:i A', $order->get_date_created ()->getOffsetTimestamp());

...

?>
```

I have my function already done, but I don't know how can I rewrite that plugin line,

**I have tried**:

```
<?php

function my_custom_filter_function($date) { 

date_default_timezone_set( 'America/Sao_Paulo' );

$dateTimeObj = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));

$dateFormatted = IntlDateFormatter::formatObject( 
  $dateTimeObj, 
  'eeee, d MMMM y, HH:mm', 
  'pt_BR' 
);

$date = ucwords($dateFormatted);
  
}

add_filter('wa_order_thank_you_override', 'my_custom_filter_function');

?>
```

But it's doesn't work, it continues showing English date.

Someone has any ideia that how can I override that plugin line?

Cheers!

Comment: Filter callback functions usually need to _return_ the modified value.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I did that, but the plugin still showing the "old" date! :(

Comment: So the function you mentioned, does it actually apply a filter named `wa_order_thank_you_override` anywhere?

Comment: @CBroe the plugin apply that "add_filter( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', 'wa_order_thank_you_override', 10, 2 );" and I would override just 1 line of the "wa_order_thank_you_override" function, if in my filter I use "woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text" intead of "woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text" I can modified some code, but when I put the "wa_order_thank_you_override" nothing happens!

Comment: So, I can do that, it's work, but in that case I need to put the whole function in my functions.php and changed what I need, I would like override just 1 line to don't put many code that i will not use in my function.php.

Comment: You can not just replace one line of code inside a function from the outside. If the function code would continue with something like `$date = add_filter('some_filter_name', $date);` - then you could hook into that, to change the value of the $date variable. But if that is not the case, then you will have no choice but to "clone" the _whole_ function.